# Enabling/Disabling Button Based on Condition in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble enabling/disabling a button (form control) based on whether all 4 cells are filled in or not (A2, A4, B2, and B4). Here's my code so far, they're all on the same sheet module.

```
Sub Disable_Button()

Dim myshape As Shape
Set myshape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FORM").Shapes("Button")
With myshape
    .ControlFormat.Enabled = False    '---> Disable the button
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 15    '---> Grey out button label
    .OnAction = ""
End With
End Sub

Sub Enable_Button()

Dim myshape As Shape
Set myshape = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FORM").Shapes("Button")
With myshape
    .ControlFormat.Enabled = True    '---> Enable the button
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1    '---> Highlight button label
    .OnAction = "Module1.TEST"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Test_Button(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address= 'I'm not sure what to put here since it won't accept multiple ranges
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value = "" Then
    Disable_Button
    Else
    Enable_Button
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

`Module1.TEST` simply outputs "SUCCESS" in cell C1. I've tested both Disable_Button and Enable_Button separately and I've confirmed that they work. However, I'm having trouble with writing code such that the button is only enabled when all 4 cells (A2, A4, B2, and B4) are all filled. I'm not sure if ByVal Target As Range is the way to go. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use and() to test the cells, specify the condition for each: and(A1="yes",B1="Blue") etc

Comment: If you want to respond to changes in cell values then you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Tons of previous posts here on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would go in the worksheet code module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Me.Range("A2:B2,A4:B4") 'the cells to monitor
    'check if any of the cells in `rng` are in `Target`
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ToggleButton (Application.CountA(rng) = 4) 'toggle button
    End If
End Sub

'switch button between enabled/disabled according to `bEnable`
Sub ToggleButton(bEnable As Boolean)
    With Me.Shapes("Button")
        .ControlFormat.Enabled = bEnable
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = IIf(bEnable, 1, 15)
        .OnAction = IIf(bEnable, "Module1.TEST", "")
    End With
End Sub
```